# Bulk modulus of Liquid helium and first sound

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superconductivity, superfluidity

Does anyone know where to find the bulk modulus of liquid helium ?

I've been looking all over the internet but everywhere I get N/A. Any tips ?

I'd need it to estimate the speed of first sound in liquid helium which is given by:

$c_1=\sqrt{\left.\frac{\partial p}{\partial\rho}\right|_\sigma}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use the inverse value, the compressibility, this one is more easilly found.

Answer (score 1):

A [Google books search](http://books.google.com/) for "bulk modulus of liquid helium" turned up this result: [Helium, edited by Paul Muljadi](http://books.google.com/books?id=M9rHRovcaO0C&pg=PA7&dq=bulk+modulus+of+liquid+helium&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2yeeUpGJGsPUkQfWu4Fo&ved=0CFYQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=bulk%20modulus%20of%20liquid%20helium&f=false). On page 7, you will find the value of the bulk modulus as `on the order 50 MPa`. There is a reference linked to this value, but it is not part of the free preview, so I cannot tell you what it is.

Comment: Alrighty! Thanks a lot already ! I'll look into it, seems to give the correct value for the speed of first sound (more or less).

Comment: Seems also that this 50MPa is for solid Helium and not liquid helium (that should be somewhere around a factor 1000 lessà

Comment: Ah, well I tried. I bet searching through the other books in the Google-book search might pop up something more accurate.

Comment: Yeah, at least thanks for trying! I've been looking on physical review letters etc. Not even [WolframAlpha][1] was able to find it. Currently I'm looking in google-books, great tip :).

[1]:http://www.wolframalpha.com/